Movie with young kids just hang round with their cars talking about their dreams
Movie is based in 60' or 70'in USA. Young kids during school break just walking and driving around. They are 16-17 but most of them have their own car.  Lots of Cars in the movie, drive-in bars,Drive-in theater etc. 
There is also a sequel based 4-5 yr later, where you can see how life revised their dreams... one is NASCAR driver, one is heading to Vietnam etc...
Do you remember such movie? Is not Spielberg production?

This sounds like American Graffiti and it's sequel More American Graffiti

yes, it sounds like it, but you need to provide more details, a link, a few lines about why it matches (even direct quotes from wikipedia or IMDb) for your answer to be a good one.
